# Nvidia drivers cause freeze when resuming from suspend

Tags: release-juno

I am wondering if anyone has a cure for an issue where usage of the nvidia drivers cause the computer to freeze when resuming from a suspended state.

I don't have this issue if I remove all the nvidia drivers, but I'm pretty sure it is defaulting to the intel gfx and I would like to use the GPU.

I have used the 390, 410, and 415 drivers.  All have the same issue.

Specs:

- Dell XPS 15 9570
- GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile
- 16 GB RAM
- i7-8750H CPU

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would check to see if the drivers are correct for your computer.

For this in the terminal enter the following command:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Then with the information of which graphic card you have, enter the repository, update and finally install the driver for your graphic card.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-XXX (You replace the XXX with your card number.)
```

Sorry for how I write, my native language is not English.

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Me too.

The only way to fix the suspend freezing is to open the "Nvidia X Server Settings" and set the Intel (power saving mode) option in the PRIME profiles panel.

Hope someone could help us with a better idea...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment on any post; instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) from the asker. | >> [Help Center](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help) <<